# iPhone UIBarButtonItem setCustomView: method?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I want to customize a UIBarButtonItem's background. Here's the code I use:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonBackground.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[editButton setCustomView:button]; // editButton is the UIBarButtonItem
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Instead of showing the UIBarButtonItem, it simply vanishes (it becomes 100% transparent). When I leave out the setCustomView method, the UIBarButtonItem appears, but is not customized.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Rich

Comment: I had a problem like you, too, is waiting to solve, I wish you good luck. this is my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950644/how-to-custom-uibarbuttonitem-in-ios5

Answer (score 3):

You should try to set the `UIButton`'s frame property to something reasonable, e.g. add a

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 40);
```

UIView's will not display if they don't have a frame set. This is why it seems invisible. It's actually there, it just has a size of 0.

Comment: I think MrMage is suggesting that you add a frame, because that's frequently the reason why UIViews don't show up.